How to scrape high volumes while avoiding proxy detection and captchas?
I’m scraping product data from HEB’s website (retailer similar to Walmart), like this https://www.heb.com/product-detail/fresh-organic-sweet-mini-peppers-16-oz/1919432
Here are my challenges:

I’m using 2 stagnant residential proxies, but they get blocked right
away, due to which I can't run my concurrency code with 3 tabs (2
proxies and my device)

I need to send ~20,000 requests, but each takes ~3 seconds, making it
a manual this a 20-hour code (residential proxy not working, handshake issue?)

Regular access denied blocks are handled by skipping requests after
30 seconds, but hCaptcha requires manual solving, interrupting the
process, due to which it needs manual intervention, I would like not
to encounter them in the first place


Currently, I am using my device but want to use residential 2 proxies (can buy more as needed), but do want to keep costs low as eventually I will need to scale to millions of requests a month. Using random user agents and undetected-chromedrive and skipping access denied links after timeouts, however, captcha links cant be skipped
Please do your magic help me scrape 20,000 URLs efficiently without being detected? However, I do not encounter a captcha in the first place since it comes after multiple requests and not in every request (1 every 100 requests). Are there better ways to handle high concurrency and avoid proxy flagging?
Here’s an outline of my current setup (irrelevant parts removed for brevity):
def setup_driver(proxy=None):
    options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    options.headless = False
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument(f"user-agent={random.choice(user_agents)}")
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    
    if proxy:
        options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy}')

    service = Service(webdriver_path)
    driver = uc.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
    return driver

user_agents = [ "Multiple user agents" ]

# Path to ChromeDriver
webdriver_path = "path to local"

# Function to extract product details from each URL
def extract_product_data(driver, url, flag, sleep):
    try:
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)  # Set timeout to 20 seconds
        driver.get(url)
        
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "__NEXT_DATA__"))
        
        if sleep:
            time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 2))
        #attempt to fool captcha, unsuccessful 

        page_source = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")
        script_tag = soup.find("script", {"id": "__NEXT_DATA__", "type": "application/json"})
        
        if script_tag:
            json_data = json.loads(script_tag.string)
            return json_data
        else:
            print(f"No JSON data found on {url}.")
            return None

Don't mind using a combination of paid web services as long as the cost is below 200 dollars for 1 mil+ requests.

Do you have rotating residential proxies?
